# Differentiating $\sin(x+y)+ \cos(x+y) = \log(x+y)$ with respect to $x$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, implicit-differentiation

It was given that $$\sin\left(x+y\right)+ \cos\left(x+y\right) = \log\left(x+y\right)$$ and I was asked to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for this.
I attempted it as:

$1-$ $$\sin\left(x+y\right)+ \cos\left(x+y\right) = \log\left(x+y\right)$$
$2-$ $$\frac{d}{dx} \left(\sin\left(x+y\right)+ \cos\left(x+y\right)\right) =\frac {d}{dx} \log\left(x+y\right)$$
$3-$ $$\cos\left(x+y\right)\left(1+\frac{dy}{dx}\right) - \sin\left(x+y\right)\left(1+\frac{dy}{dx}\right) = \frac{ \left(1+\frac{dy}{dx}\right) }{x+y}$$

And now in step $4$, term $\left(1+\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$ gets cancelled from both sides and we are left with

$$\cos\left(x+y\right) - \sin\left(x+y\right)= \frac{1}{x+y}.$$

So we don't get any term containing $\frac{dy}{dx}$. So how can I find out $\frac{dy}{dx}$ if I am not getting it, same problem arises if I differentiate it again.

Comment: the log means the usual ln?

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: Your step labeled $2-$ is wrong. From what you wrote below that it appears that you meant $\displaystyle \frac d {dx} ( (\sin(x+y)+ \cos(x+y)) =\log(x+y) ) = \frac d {dx} \log (x+y).$ If so, you should have written that. NOTA BENE: DO NOT write $\dfrac {dy}{dx}$ when you mean $\dfrac d {dx}. \qquad$

Comment: Thanks @Michael Hardy, I have made correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can cancel $\left(1+\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)$ only when $\left(1+\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)\neq0$. But in this case:
\begin{align*}
\sin(x+y)+\cos(x+y)=\log(x+y)\\
\Rightarrow \dfrac{d}{dx}[\sin(x+y)]+\dfrac{d}{dx}[\cos(x+y)]&=\dfrac{d}{dx}[\log(x+y)]\\
\Rightarrow \cos(x+y)\cdot\left(1+\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)-\sin(x+y)\cdot\left(1+\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)&=\dfrac{1}{x+y}\cdot\left(1+\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)\\
\Rightarrow\left(1+\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)\left[\cos(x+y)-\sin(x+y)-\dfrac{1}{x+y}\right]&=0
\end{align*}

So either $\left(1+\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)=0\quad$ or, $\quad\cos(x+y)-\sin(x+y)=\dfrac{1}{x+y}$.

Therefore, $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=-1\quad$ or, $\quad\cos(x+y)-\sin(x+y)=\dfrac{1}{x+y}$.

Comment: Hey! I got it. That's what I was looking for. I wanted someone to show how that $\frac{dy}{dx}=-1$ and you have showed it succesfully.

Comment: @Avi If you've any other doubts please ask ... always happy to help.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that the equation you got from differentiating holds when $\frac{dy}{dx} = -1.$ This is your solution. Don't cancel that out, rearrange and cancel the other stuff out!

What's going on can be seen by briefly substituting $z$ in for $x+y$ and looking at $\cos(z)+\sin(z)=\log(z).$ You see this is a transcendental equation with maybe a couple solutions. So for any solution $z_0$ you have $y = z_0-x$ as a solution to your functional equation. Note that $dy/dx = -1.$ Solutions $y(x)$ generated this way are the only 'nice' solutions

(And it's the only solution provided there is only one solution to the transcendental equation. If there's a discrete set then you can do weird things like $y = z(x)-x$ where $z(x)$ hops between the solutions, but of course these solutions are not continuous.)

You notice when you cancel out the $(1+dy/dx)$ you have another transcendental equation that could hold instead, but that's unimportant since the solutions of interest all have $dy/dx=-1.$ (And furthermore it seems unlikely that $\cos(z)+\sin(z) = \log(z)$ and  $\cos(z)-\sin(z) = 1/z$ have simultaneous solutions, so this second equation is likely irrelevant since it must simultaneously hold with the first. )

Comment: So does this mean that I can't write that equation in the form like $\frac{dy}{dx}= other- terms$. that is I can't seperate $\frac{dy}{dx}$ from the equation.

Comment: @Avi You've differentiated properly to get a valid equation involving the derivative and see that it holds when $dy/dx = -1$. It's a little unusual in that there seem to be other possibilities where $dy/dx$ can be anything and the other equation holds, but what are the odds of that one holding simultaneously with original equation? This requires a little more thought than a standard implicit differentiation problem, but further analysis shows dy/dx = -1 was to be expected.

Comment: @Avi I feel like I might have obscured the fact that if you solve that equation for $dy/dx$ you do indeed get $dy/dx = -1$. So I think the answer to what you're asking is no.

Comment: Also thanks to you for your help, you too have said the same thing but I found the another answer more easy to understand.